# How to wake up MacBook Pro with external display with lid closed?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, sleep-wake

Mouse or keyboard activity does not wake up the computer. Is there a way to do this without opening the lid?

Answer (score 10):

He's right; clamshell mode will not work unless the Mac-top is on external power.

Wake-on-mouse was last seen in Snow Leopard, it's been keyboard-only for some years now.

If your Mac-top is one of the New Breed (ie. it has a T2 chip) you can only wake a sleeping clam-book with a directly-connected (can't be in a hub) USB keyboard or a previously-paired Bluetooth keyboard.

Comment: Please make your answer stand on its own, without referring to a different answer. There might be multiple answers over time, so any reference is difficult anyway.

Comment: I'm so thankful for your answer. This was driving me crazy, glad to know that was necessary.

Comment: Wow, that’s a stupid limitation. At least now I know to stop trying. Thanks.

Comment: For my mid 2017 MBP running 10.15 (I think), power and monitor are the only requirements - it wakes on both bluetooth mouse and keyboard 

Comment: I have a 'previous' bleutooth connect keyboard. But it will not be doing anything. Or is it meant by actively bluetooth connected keyboard when going to sleep. I do have a keyboard serving both a windows PC and a Mac. And, who wonders..., the Mac tends to fall asleep when I use the keyboard with windows...

Comment: Macbook Pro 2019 16 inch running Big Sur: keyboard wake no longer works with external USB *OR* built-in keyboard. Only power button works.

Answer (score 5):

Attach a charger and then you can wake it up with a keybord or mouse.